# XCode 6.1 breakpoints mis-placed / break at incorrect line

Tags: c++, xcode

I have this issue for a while. Since I started to use xocde 4. Now I am using xcode 6.1 on OSX Yosemite. The symptom is something like I put break point at line 735. When I am debugging the code, xcode breaks on line 743. It seems that is issue happens randomly.

Since the project that I am working on is created by scripts. The issue can be fixed by deleting and regenerating the project files (.xcworkspace and .xcodeproj).
or sometimes can be fixed by clean&rebuild whole project.

The Build Settings -> Optimization Level is set to None[-O0].

Is there anything else I could fix the problem faster/easier?
And anyone know the cause of the problem?

Thanks

Comment: If you can, print an *interleaved* assembly listing of the functions that you set breakpoints in.  Verify that the compiler has not optimized anything out.  Another reason is your symbol file is not synchronized to the {debug} executable.

Comment: If the problem is optimization. Clean&rebuild or regenerating project won't fix the problem, right? I will try to delete .app file to see if it fix the problem. Thanks